# What is rule behind @font-face?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I learning CSS and I have one confusion with @font-face.

I have seen many websites using @font-face three to four times on their CSS file with the difference in font-weight.

like the below example create three @font-face with the same name. So which one will apply if I create one

tag and use the font-family: 'Test' in it.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Test';
  src: url('path') format('woff2'),
  url('path') format('woff'),
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Test';
  src: url('path') format('woff2'),
  url('path') format('woff'),
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Test';
  src: url('path') format('woff2'),
  url('path') format('woff'),
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

The below exam is taken from w3schools. Here they defined @font-face twice with the same font-family name. My question how it is decided which font-family is applied to which element ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
@font-face {
  font-family: myFirstFont;
  src: url(sansation_light.woff);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: myFirstFont;
  src: url(sansation_bold.woff);
  font-weight: bold;
}

div {
  font-family: myFirstFont;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The @font-face Rule</h1>

<div>With CSS, websites can use fonts other than the pre-selected "web-safe" fonts.</div>

</body>
</html>
```